# SSRS 2008 Error "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object." while creating subscription

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

While creating a subscription on reporting server i am facing an error "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

There is a drop down on report with more than 1000 items in it. Report is working fine when I run it from reporting server by select all the values in drop down. I understand that this issue can be resolved by increasing the value for key aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys.

My question is why it fails only while creating subscription and not when running the report.

Comment: when do you get this error, when you click on `new subscription`, or after you click OK on the subscription page?

Comment: when i click on on subscription page.